# How to Keep Label Height Constant while Embedding it in StackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, height, uistackview

I have a `UILabel` and a `UIButton` that I need to put in a vertical `UIStackView`. The design of the screen is such that I need to give some background colour to the `UILabel` and it needs to have some fixed height and the font of the `UILabel` is small.

Could anybody please help me understand if its possible to keep the height constant while inserting it in the stackview since stackview compresses its height otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656621/adjusting-uiview-height-inside-uistackview-control

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks a lot! How do I accept your answer?