# Change value of UILabel inside UIStackView in .xib file

Tags: ios, xib, uistackview

I am creating a vertical `UIStackView` inside a `UIView` and placing `UILabel` elements inside it.

[image]

Now, I want to change the height of `Label` inside the `UIStackView`. But the height property seems to be disabled.

[image]

Alternatively, I am able to set height constraint for the label and change it's value programatically. I want to know if there is a way to change the value in the XIB itself as my purpose is to set a static value and cut down on adding code for it.

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656621/adjusting-uiview-height-inside-uistackview-control

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik. That did help.

Comment: happy to hear, welcome dude...

Answer (score 0):

First add UIView in UIStackView and Then Add UILabel under view. Set label's constraint. Now you can just change the UIView Frame from Size inspector, it will automatically change the label frame. [image]

Comment: In this case, I need not use a stack view itself. The UIView itself will be enough, right?

Comment: @Sowndharya Yes Just one stackView as I have used, no other. UIView inside stackview will be enough to handle this case.